# How to format a decimal datatype in powershell as an ipv6 address in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, formatting, ipv6

The only datatype in powershell that I'm aware of that can store 128-bits is the `[decimal]`and while I seem to be able to store the variable:

```
PS /home/leeand00/> [decimal]$ipv6addr=0x20010db81234
```

I don't seem to be able to pull it back out again (clearly that's a decimal):

```
PS /home/leeand00/>$ipv6addr                
35188897223220
```

And I thought maybe this would do it, but it does not:

```
PS /home/leeand00/>"{0:x4}" -f ($ipv6addr)
Error formatting a string: Format specifier was invalid..                       
At line:1 char:1
+ "{0:x4}" -f $ipv6addr
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({0:x4}:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatError
```

The above error doesn't make sense because...the datatypes is decimal

```
PS /home/leeand00/Documents/lifehacker organized/docs> $ipv6addr.GetType().Name 
Decimal
```

PS, I'm aware there are tools for working with IPv6 in Powershell, but I'm just trying to perform some simple binary operations when learning about it.

Comment: Apart from any answer, I don't think that a `decimal` is the correct type to hold a complete IPv6 address. Although a `decimal` might hold 128 bits, it can't hold an integer larger than a 96 bits: `[math]::log([decimal]::MaxValue) / [math]::log(2)`. I guess you will need to create a byte array: `$IPv6 = New-Object Byte[] 128` or an array of 8 UInt16 types (`$IPv6 = New-Object UInt16[] 8`) where each  UInt16 ([Hextet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hextet)) represents a 16 bit IPv6 group.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell is just using the underlying .NET types and converters.  The 'X' specifier does not support decimal input:

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

> Result: A hexadecimal string.
>
> Supported by: Integral types only.
>
> Precision specifier: Number of digits in the result string.

If you have a decimal, one option to make this work is to first cast to an `int`, `int64` or `uint64` (depending on size of input):

```
"0x{0:x4}" -f [int64]ipv6addr
```